# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens entre MySQL e PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Estou com essa dúvida faz um bom tempo, vejo algumas pessoas recomendando o uso do PostgreSQL, mas não fica claro as vantagens e desvantagens em relação ao MySQL. Quero definir o banco que irei utilizar em meu projeto e gostaria de saber qual o melhor.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Primeiro um lembrete: o MySQL deixou de ser "100% público", o dono dele é a Oracle, ao passo que o PostgreSQL é 100% público e dá suporte a diversos outros projetos 100% públicos, como o [PostGIS](http://postgis.org/).

O MySQL foi bem defendido na discussão, e não discordo da maior parte... Me resta então, como usuário também de PostgreSQL, de anos, defendê-lo um pouco.

### Questões de mercado

- Para um software aberto competir com concorrentes bastante agressivos no *lobby* e no *marketing*, como o Oracle e o MS-SQL-Server, surgiram empresas que dão o mesmo tipo de suporte, a exemplo da [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com) — além do suporte pago, ela criou um pacote gratuito de instalação *plug-and-play* ótimo, que deixou para trás o MySQL.
- A "hospedagem básica" de MySQL só se manteve forte e difundida pelo poder do [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29), de anos atrás, quando os softwares proprietários tentavam explorar descaradamente os provedores... Virou tradição, o MySQL é tão "pop" quanto WordPress numa hospedagem, ou tão natural quanto [SQL Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Lite) num aplicativo Android.
- A hospedagem de sistemas críticos, empresariais e aplicações mais sofisticadas, requer PostgreSQL como solução OpenSource. Claro o número de provedores "não-básicos" no mercado é muitíssimo menor (o comum é a empresa internalizar seu data-center). De qualquer modo, quando a "hospedagem básica" (a mais barata) oferece PostgreSQL, o preço é o mesmo que MySQL.

### Questões de conceito

- *[SGBD totalmemte transactional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing)* (aquela coisa de COMMIT/ROLLBACK): o PostgreSQL sempre foi, e inclui todos os comandos-padrão de DDL para isso. Internamente ele evita o "locking" usando [multiversion concurrency control (MVCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) e [seriação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability). O MySQL antigo não possuia ROLLBACK, mas justamente isso que o tornava mais rápido (!)...
- *[Escalabilidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalabilidade)* é um termo meio vago e amplo, mas em geral quer dizer  "habilidade de manipular uma porção crescente de trabalho de forma uniforme, ou estar preparado para crescer". Neste sentido, quem tem capacidade de crescer muito e muito em volume de dados sem deteriorar performance, ou crescer muito em termos de complexidade ou uso de mais módulos, é o PostgreSQL.
- [SQL Orientado a Objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_SQL): novamente o PostgreSQL cumpre com a promessa, sempre permitiu herança, assim como definição de *custom types*, etc.
- [Banco de dados distribuído](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database): as tais "asynchronous data calls" (já citadas por aqui) são uma das peças-chave, que permitem o PostgreSQL se comportar realmente como *distribuído* (o MySQL não é pode 100%).

### Padronização

Diversos comandos são "só do MySQL", ele não é muito "padrãozão"... Ao passo que o PostgreSQL, ele respeita à risca os padrões quando se propõe a fazê-lo, e fez na maior parte dos seus módulos, na orientação a objeto, e fez inclusive no [XML desde a versão 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-xml.html), que nem existia no MySQL (hoje [na 5.6 ainda é restrito a duas funções](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xml-functions.html)).

Para aqueles que questionam a conformidade do PostgreSQL, por favor leiam o [SQL Conformance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/features.html): ele é aderente à maior parte do [padrão SQL:2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011), coisa que o MySQL não é.

## Preferências e tendências

Aí vão só opiniões, sem me preocupar em sustentá-las, ou lembrar se são realmente populares:

- Se vai precisar de transações (ROLLBACK), já é indício que não precisa de MySQL... O PostgreSQL é que nasceu com isso.
- Se você é o programador e o gerente do seu projeto, não fique "amarrado ao básico", exija da sua infra-estrutura  profissionalismo (é muito cômodo dizer que não conhece), exija o SQL com maior expressividade de linguagem, escalabilidade, etc.
- Com servidores mais e mais poderosos, não faz mais sentido usar a justificativa maior do MySQL, que era "economizar CPU". Se precisa *mesmo* economizar, pense no [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).
- Com a facilidade de [virtualização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) nos servidores Web — você pode ter uma aplicação Microsoft numa VM, e o serviço SQL dela em PostgreSQL sob Linux em outra VM —, não é mais preciso prender o sistema inteiro a  "soluções Oracle" ou a "soluções Microsoft"... Faz sentido usar padrões interoperáveis e software livre.

Comment: na parte de padronização, você citou "hoje na 5.1 aninda é restrito em duas funções.". A versão atual do MySQL é a 5.6, também restrita as mesma duas funções. Tomei a liberdade de editar sua resposta. Abraços

Comment: Obrigado! Mantive as suas correções técnicas e acrescentei gramaticais... Com seu comentário aproveitei para reler, e descobrir meus erros de redação (devem ter muitos mais, são piores do que erros de software, nunca acabam!)

Comment: Gostaria de complementar sua resposta com relação a parte que você diz que "MySQL deixou de ser "100% público", o dono dele é a Oracle". Isso está 100% correto. No entanto, a comunidade fez um *fork* do código-fonte do MySQL e criou o [**MariaDB**](https://mariadb.org/pt-br), que substitui muito bem o MySQL e está sob licença GPLv2.

Comment: Não seria _serialização_ ao invés de _seriação_? (Falou o chato :))

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Os votos rápidos me surpreenderam, o PostgreSQL tem lá seus fãs e faltava ele ser defendido... Mas para não ser fanático, e garantirmos precisão, abri a resposta para Wiki: qualquer um pode editar para corrigir. Sobre a [seriação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seria%C3%A7%C3%A3o), vide link, aparentemente é esse o termo (não confundir com "serialização de XML" e de outras estruturas).

Comment: Faltou só falar do PL/SQL, que é parcialmente suportado pelo PG no pgPL/SQL. Tirando isso, estou até emocionado com a resposta!

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, Sim (!) ficou faltando, assim como lembrar que pode ainda criar funções de alta performance com C, e escrever funções reutilizando algoritmos prontos de Javascript, Java, Perl, R, etc. ... Mas repare que abri a resposta como WIKI, **você mesmo pode editar**!

Comment: O Postgres é um DB melhor pra armazenar JSON que os NoSQL especializados!

Answer (score 26):

Você não deu muitos parâmetros de como pretende usar o banco de dados. Isso faz muita diferença. Vou tentar colocar os dois cenários principais.

Também não disse qual banco ele ou as pessoas que trabalham com ele conhece melhor. Talvez por não conhecer nenhum deles. Em quase qualquer cenário, usar o que você está acostumado é o melhor caminho, não importa muito outros motivos. Nos casos de não conhecer nenhum, o melhor é procurar uma solução que resolva qualquer cenário que você venha encontrar. Neste caso o PostgreSQL é a melhor solução. Preste atenção, ele é melhor que outras soluções em poucos cenários, na maioria dos casos, qualquer solução de BD atenderá a necessidade.

## Websites

Se você vai usar para websites simples, normais, provavelmente você vai querer algo simples de instalar (apesar que provavelmente vai usar uma hospedagem onde o bd já está instalado), de dar manutanção e de programar o acesso. Esse é um caso em que o MySQL costuma se sair melhor do que o PostgreSQL. O PostgreSQL é certamente mais complexo, não há dúvida sobre isso.

Mas se quer algo simples mesmo, então é melhor pensar na terceira via. O SQLite é mais simples ainda, mais padronizado e mais confiável que o MySQL. O único problema dele é que ele não permite grande escala. Oficialmente eles dizem que 99% do websites podem usar o SQLite tranquilamente. Eu digo pela minha experiência que é pelo menos 99,9%. Na maioria dos cenários ele vai escalar até melhor que o MySQL. Quando entrar em um cenário onde ele passa ter problemas, o MySQL pode ter problemas também.

Não estou dizendo que o MySQL não é bom. Claro que é. Mas o grande motivo das pessoas usarem ele é porque todo mundo usa e não porque ele é necessário, porque ele faz algo melhor.

## Enterprise

Para aplicações corporativas, o PostgreSQL brilha mais que o MySQL. Tem inúmeros casos de uso do MySQL em ambiente corporativo com enorme sucesso, não entenda que o MySQL não é bom neste cenário. O SQLite já fica mais restrito, ele pode ser usado apenas em redes bem pequenas e começando perder uma das suas vantagens em relação ao MySQL que é a confiabilidade.

Tenha em mente que de todos os BDs mais conhecidos ele é o único que [não é full ACID](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#ACID_Compliance). Até o SQLite é.

O PostgreSQL não fica devendo muito aos sistemas normalmente mais usados em aplicações corporativas como Oracle e SQL Server. Tem até alguns recursos exclusivos. O MySQL resolve bem quase todas as situações, é possível resolver outras com um pouco mais de esforço ou com dificuldades, mas ele deixa a desejar em cenários mais complexos.

## Correções

Resolvi colocar uma resposta porque tem vários erros nas respostas postadas até agora. Na verdade a resposta do Peter Krauss é muito boa. Vou começar por ela por ter alguns pontos que podem ser melhor esclarescidos.

#### ROLLBACK

Foi dito que o MySQL não tem ROLLBACK. Isso não é uma verdade absoluta. Primeiro precisamos entender uma das características do MySQL. Ele permite vários engines de storage.

Dá para entender o que o Peter Krauss disse, porque quase todo mundo associa o MySQL ao engine de storage chamado MyISAM. Ele é que deu a vantagem de performance ao MySQL durante muito anos, ele que é usado na mioria dos cenários, principalmente para websites. Realmente o MyISAM não tem ROLLBACK. Mas o InnoDB que é outro engine de storage, tem ROLLBACK sim. Mas isso não ajuda tanto. Porque em qualquer caso, o MySQL tem dificuldades em manter o chamado full ACID. Ou seja, o banco de dados pode se perder em algumas situações. Muito específicas, mas acontece. A arquitetura do MySQL, independente do engine de storage escolhido tem dificuldade de manter os dados em ordem am alguns casos extremos.

Algumas pessoas acham que a única vantagem do MySQL é quando usado com o MyISAM, que tem algumas vantagens, principalmente de performance. Outras acham que o InnoDB é o único caminho a seguir com o MySQL por dar mais ferramentas, ser mais escalável e mais confiável em alguns cenários. Eu sou da opinião que nos cenários em que o MyISAM é uma boa solução, o SQLite é melhor. E nos cenários em que o InnoDB é bom, o PostgreSQL é melhor.

O PostgreSQL é mais poderoso mas tem o custo de ser mais complexo. A grande vantagem do MySQL em relação ao PostgreSQL é ser mais simples, e com o InnoDB isso quase é perdido.

Então a resposta dele não está errada, mas não está completa.

#### Escalabilidade

A escalabilidade é possível em ambos os casos, e de certa forma ainda é mais fácil no MySQL na maioria dos cenários onde realmente precisa de muita escala, o que é raro. Mas o PostgreSQL tem dado prioridade para melhorar essa situação e não está longe de ser mais fácil escalar massivamente no PostgreSQL. Note que eu **não** disse que o MySQL é melhor nesse ponto. O PostgreSQL tem muito mais formas e ferramentas de escalar ou evitar soluções complexas em casos médios, alguns já citados na outra resposta. Quase todo mundo superestima a necessidade de escalabilidade de BD. O hardware é tão poderoso hoje que esquemas complexos de escalabilidade raramente são necessários. Quase tudo o que se lê nos blogs sobre escalabilidade hoje em dia, estão falando de websites de enorme sucesso como o SO. Não é para os casos comuns. Esses casos estão tão dominados que não precisa falar tanto. O PostgreSQL é melhor para scale up (rodar mais na mesma máquina) e o MySQL é mais fácil, só mais fácil, não melhor, em scale out (usar várias máquinas para dar escala). O PostgreSQL usa até o último talo da máquina para depois você precisar de mais máquinas, o MySQL, você precisa de mais máquinas rapidamente, mas ainda em 2014 é mais fácil adicionar máquinas para o MySQL. Em 2015 isso pode ser diferente.

#### SQL orientado a objeto

Esqueça SQL orientado a objeto. Isso não deu certo em lugar algum. Isso era algo que deveria existir no PostgreSQL mas foi abandonado há muito tempo. Está lá algumas ferramentas, mas elas são problemáticas, limitadas e não recebem atualizações. Você não vê aplicações sérias usando esse recurso e é algo questionável na mioria dos casos.

#### Padronização

Finalmente e já começando questionar as outras respostas, o MySQL é totalmente fora do padrão ANSI e inventa alguma maluquices que causa tremedeiras em vários administradores e programadores. Na verdade essas maluquices são as principais vantgens do MySQL, são elas que facilitam o seu uso. Você tem que escolher o que quer. Mas não digam que o MySQL é padronizado. Não sei como uma resposta que diga isso pode ter muitos votos. Provavelmente fan boys do MySQL votaram.

PostgreSQL você tem que saber usar para dar certo. MySQL dá certo um monte de coisa mesmo sem saber porque. Até que você fica maluco para descobri porque não funciona mais. No MySQL existe o mais ou menos correto. Tem gente que gosta disso.

#### Instalação

Hoje não dá para dizer claramente que é mais fácil instalar o MySQL do que o PostgreSQL. Claro que você tem que saber de algumas coisas para fazer melhor, tem que conhecer o [instalador da EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload). E se você acha que instalação é um problema, não sei o que vai fazer para administrar um BD que é absurdamente mais complexo. Raramente você instala, isso não deve ser levado em consideração. Mas se você tem um cenário que faz muitas instalações, vai ficar tão experiente que não importa qual é mais fácil, você vai dominar qualquer coisa. E nesses cenários, Next, Next, Next, Finish é a última coisa que você deveria usar.

## Garantias (segurança, confiabilidade)

> Se sua preocupação é com a segurança escolha PostgeSQL, mas se for escalabilidade vá de MySql.

Segurança ou confiabilidade? É preciso definir bem do que está se falando. Segurança, confiabilidade ou escalabilidade, se você quer o melhor, é o PostgreSQL. Vou repetir, o MySQL só é mais simples, consequentemente pior. Ambos são seguros, cada um tem sua vantagem específica.

Vou reafirmar aqui que nem o InnoDB suporta full ACID. Ele é ACID em certas circunstâncias. Ou seja, não é ACID. Tentei achar um site que mostra problemas que o InnoDB sofre, mas não consegui.

## O que não foi dito ainda

O PostgreSQL suporta algumas variações de storage. Não chegam ser engines totalmente separados, tão diferentes, mas você pode escolher a melhor variante para cada situação e isso é bem integrado com todo banco de dados. AO contrário do MySQL que o engine separado não pode fazer algumas coisas porque o MySQL dificulta ou impede. O PostgreSQL tenta usar a melhor forma de armazenar no mesmo engine.

Ele também tem várias formas de indexação. Para otimização, escolher o método de indexação correto é melhor que o storage dos dados principais. Isso faz o PostgreSQL bater sistemas mais poderosos em certos cenários.

Quer performance máxima e não precisa da confiabilidade? O PostgreSQL suporta também. Só não é o default e não é recomendado. O maior problema do PostgreSQL é que as pessoas não sabem de tudo o que ele é capaz, não é falta de capacidade. Ele opta por um caminho mais "enterprise", ou mais profissional, deixando você opcioanlemente deixá-lo mais "frouxo" como o MySQL é por default.

Tem formas de deixar o MySQL um pouco melhor, mas aí acabou a simplicidade dele. Não existe almoço grátis.

Na verdade quando você tenta fazer algumas coisas mais complexas, o PostgreSQL tem ferramentas mais apropriadas (melhores JOINs, subqueries, CTEs, funções customizadas, estruturas de dados mais poderosas, extensibilidade, etc).

Pela quantidade de usuários do MySQL, deve ter mais profissinais com P maiúsculo trabalhando com ele, o que mostra que a tecnologia não é importante. Mas percentualmente, você vai encontrar mais Profissionais usando o PostgreSQL. Ele não se dá bem com amadores. Curiosamente o SQLite deveria fazer mais sucesso entre os amadores, mas talvez esses sejam tão amadores que nem conseguem descobrir o SQLite. Ou talvez o fato do SQLite exigir que se faça as coisas corretamente, mesmo que de forma simples, afaste os amadores que se preocupam apans com o resultado, não com o resultado correto.

Note que a capacidade do administrador em fazer o banco de dados trabalhar bem é sempre mais importante que a tecnologia escolhida.

## Informações adicionais sobre comparações

Em um dos links que postei tem uma extensa comparação dos dois, por isso não vou entrar em detalhes.

Cuidado com as comparações de versões antigas. Principalmente quando só uma delas é antiga.

Muito do que disse aqui é uma simplificação. Tenha isso em mente. Nada é banco de dados pode ser analisado de forma tão simplista. Algumas pessoas facilmente podem achar que é diferente.

Eu não acho, mas se você acha que popularidade é importante: http://db-engines.com/en/ranking Releia o que o Peter Krauss escreveu antes de dar muito valor a isso. E veja que esse ranking tem um critério próprio. O SQLite é o banco de dados mais usado no mundo. Deve ter vários bancos SQLite no seu computador e você nem sabe.

Na [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) tem uma comparação de vários sistemas que ajuda bastante para ter uma noção inicial das diferenças.

Particularmente uso o PostgreSQL na maioria dos casos. Resolve tudo o que preciso, nunca me deixa na mão. Nos casos em que a simplicidade é mais importante, o SQLite resolve meu problema. Faz tempo que não acho um caso que preciso da simplicidade e um poder superior ao que o SQLite dá mas não tanto que o MySQL também não tem. Então o MySQL ficou para os casos em que sou obrigado a usá-lo por razões não técnicas.

Você terá que avaliar por conta própria o que é o seu caso. Dei uma quantidade boa de informações e indiquei onde pode achar uma comparação mais cabeça-a-cabeça deles.

Algum erro aqui? É possível, mas fiz o meu melhor para o momento.

Answer (score 12):

Este site explica algumas coisas que podem servir para sua resposta.

Fonte: http://www.infowester.com/postgremysql.php

Aqui vai um breve resumo:

MySQL ou PostgreSQL, qual usar? Ambos são muito bons e não fazem feio diante das alternativas pagas. Além disso, possuem recursos e vantagens em comum, o que significa que, para a maioria das aplicações, ambos podem ser usados. Na verdade, o correto não é tentar descobrir qual é o melhor, mas em que situação um ou outro deve ser utilizado.

O PostgreSQL é otimizado para aplicações complexas, isto é, que envolvem grandes volumes de dados ou que tratam de informações críticas. Assim, para um sistema de comércio eletrônico de porte médio/alto, por exemplo, o PostGreSQL é mais interessante, já que esse SGBD é capaz de lidar de maneira satisfatória com o volume de dados gerado pelas operações de consulta e venda.

O MySQL, por sua vez, é focado na agilidade. Assim, se sua aplicação necessita de retornos rápidos e não envolve operações complexas, o MySQL é a opção mais adequada, pois é otimizado para proporcionar processamento rápido dos dados e tempo curto de resposta sem exigir muito do hardware. Se você precisa, por exemplo, de um banco de dados para armazenar o conteúdo do seu site, de seu fórum ou necessita manter um cadastro de usuários de um portal, o MySQL "serve como uma luva", pois tais aplicações não necessitam dos recursos avançados que o PostgreSQL oferece.

Comment: Em suma: se sua aplicação exige do SGBD algo mais do que uma simples armazenagem de dados opte pelo PostgreSQL. Pode-se também acrescentar: uma excelente documentação e uma comunidade atuante e prestativa.

Answer (score 9):

Para escolher a melhor solução de SGBD para seu projeto é preciso saber mais informações sobre a arquitetura, por exemplo, se é uma aplicação WEB com arquitetura em camadas ou cliente/servidor, etc. No entanto algumas características são gerais e afetam todas as aplicações.

1. Padronização da linguagem: MySql é melhor
2. Instalação: MySql é mais fácil
3. Hospedagem de SGBD: a quantidade de provedores WEB que suportam MySql é muito maior.
4. Se sua preocupação é com a segurança escolha PostgeSQL, mas se for escalabilidade vá de MySql.
5. PostgreSQL suporta *Asynchronous data calls* e o MySql não.
6. ACID - atomicity, consistency, isolation e durability : **ambos** suportam e no MySql você deve usar a *InnoDB storage engine*

Existem vários outros itens importantes a considerar na escolha do SGBD. Esta lista acima é apenas a ponta do Icebergue. Uma resposta mais completa depende de mais informações sobre o projeto e a aplicação.

Answer (score 5):

O PostgreSQL é excelente. Implantei em um cliente, pequena/média empresa, há 7 anos, e nunca tive nenhum "bug". Sem, sequer, substituir o sistema aplicativo do cliente, mantendo todos os programas originais, de modo fácil, foi substituído o, instável, 
Accesss dos programas pelo PostgerSQL. Facílimo de dar manutenção. em empresas pequenas e médias, sequer, necessita de DBManager. Um programador esperto consegue parametrizar, implementar e dar suporte e manutenção. Muito rápido, seguro e poderoso. Pode ser usado por grandes empresas pois é robusto, eficiente e eficaz. Nada deve ao Oracle.

E... De graça, mesmo.