# PostGresql ou MySQL

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo uma Sistema ERP Web e estou precisando definir o banco de dados que vou utilizar acredito, preciso de Banco de dados free e estou em duvidas entre o MySql e o PostGresql, queria uma opinião de vcs em relação ao Genexus com os 2 bancos que sitei o qual seria o mais indicado para trabalhar com aplicação desenvolvida no Genexus.

Obrigado

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste artigo http://www.devmedia.com.br/postgresql-x-mysql-qual-escolher/3923

Comment: Repetido em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8609/quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens-entre-mysql-e-postgresql/8610#8610